# Quotient Ring in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have the following ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$, $I = (2 - \sqrt{-5})$. I want to know how to explicitly represent $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]/I$ and determine if this is a field.

I have tried $$\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]/I \cong \mathbb{Z}[x]/(2-x,x^2+5)$$ but I am stuck.

Comment: Compare with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1893880/finding-an-isomorphism-between-mathbf-z-sqrt-5-big-3-1-sqrt-5-and), or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58901/question-on-quotient-of-mathbbz-sqrtn-by-a-non-zero-ideal-i).

Answer (score 3):

We have:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]/I 
&=
(\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2+5))\ /\ (2-X) 
\\
&=
\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2+5,\ 2-X) 
\\
&=
(\mathbb{Z}[X]/(2-X))\ /\ (X^2+5) \text{ and via } X\to 2
\\
&=
\mathbb{Z}\ /\ (2^2+5) 
\\
&=
\mathbb{Z}\ /\ (9) 
\end{aligned}
$$
which is not a field.

Comment: In fact, working modulo $I$ in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ we have $3\cdot 3=9=(2-\sqrt{-5})(2+\sqrt{-5})$. It remains to show $3\ne 0$ modulo $I$. Well, if $3\in I$, then we would have a relation of the shape $3=(a+b\sqrt{-5})(2-\sqrt{-5})$, taking norms then would give $9=(a^2+5b^2)\cdot 9$, so $a^2+5b^2=1$, so $b=0$ and $a=\pm1$, contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you had in mind? $$(2-x,x^2+5)=(2-x,2x-x^2,x^2+5)=(2-x,5+2x)=(2-x,9)$$

In $\Bbb Z[x]/I$, $x$ acts like $2$ and $9$ as $0$.

Comment: Generally $\ (x\!-\!a,f(x)) = (x\!-\!a, f(x)\bmod x\!-\!a) = (x\!-\!a, f(a))\ $ for $\, f\in\Bbb Z[x]\ \ $